# How do make a loading screen code with C++?

Tags: visual-c++, console

I'm trying to create a loading bar or a loading screen after a certain command. In other words I was trying to substitute the code system("PAUSE") that shows "press any key to continue...", with a code that creates a loading screen, instead. Is that possible? Sorry if my question doesn't make sense whatsoever, I'm still new to programming.

Comment: There are literally millions of different loading screens, can you give an example of what YOU want?

Comment: How about something that shows this:
                            
                                   Loading. . .

and it just stays there for like maybe 3 seconds then it would continue to the next code, just to pretend that it's actually loading.

Comment: But do you want the "loading screen" to be text on the console, a popup window, something else?

Comment: Just to be text on the console, that's it. no need for a window. thanks.